# Skydrive API change permission of folder?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, onedrive

I'm trying to change the access permissions of a folder on skydrive, but it isn't working.

```
Dictionary<string, object> folderData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
folderData.Add("shared_with", "Everyone (public)");
LiveConnectClient client = new LiveConnectClient(session);
client.PutAsync(folderId, folderData);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the permissions are read-only.
Like this, reading permission of folder.

```
...
    void Properties_Completed(object sender, LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs e)//completed
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            IDictionary<string,object> result = e.Result;
            object shr = result["shared_with"];
            IDictionary<string, object> permission = shr as IDictionary<string, object>;
            string access = permission["access"].ToString();
        }
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you need to have the **wl.skydrive_update** scope active to update data related to SkyDrive entities. Also, the permissions are read-only (details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243648.aspx)).